# Проблема с редиректом существующих файлов

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно склеить два сайта, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Если на старом сайте **присутствует** файл, скажем, `http://old-site.com/logo.png`, 
то почему-то не проиходит  редирект на `http://new-site.com/logo.png`
И наоборот, если какого-то файла нет, то редиректит как надо. С остальными url все работает правильно

```
Redirect 301 / http://new-site.com/
```

или

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.com/$1  [L,R=301]
```

весь код

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

RewriteBase /

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#RewriteRule .* / [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

Redirect 301 / http://new-site.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-site.com/$1  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @Tim Krasko, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

И покажите весь код редиректов.

Вообще просто удалить все, кроме `.htaccess`, нельзя?)

Comment: добавил код, но не понял насчет "Вообще просто удалить все, кроме .htaccess, нельзя?)"